# How do I make a control invisible on my form

Tags: c#, forms

I tried using combobox1.Visible = false; but then it doesn't go invisible. It just gets uninteractable. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to use `Enable` property rather like

```
combobox1.Enable = false;
```

Comment: The Enable property of the combobox control would not make the control invisible.  It would actually cause the control to become inactive.

Comment: @JamesShaw, I know that very well but see OP's post; he is actually using the visible property to `false`. Which makes me guess that probably he wanted to disable it rather.

Comment: I jus want to make it invisible so that you can't even see it

Comment: @SipheMbude, Then the `Visible` property should do it like `combobox1.Visible = false;`. You need to provide more details if this doesn't invisible the control.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:
    combobox1.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed